# Ruby on Rails custom update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, triggers, custom-action

I want to update member_id, which triggers update of :location_stock.

I have got these custom actions in 
**costumes_and_cost_records_controller.rb**:

```
def rent
    @costumes_and_cost_record = CostumesAndCostRecord.find(params[:costumes_and_cost_record_id])
end

def rent_method
    @costumes_and_cost_record = CostumesAndCostRecord.find(params[:costumes_and_cost_record_id])
    @costumes_and_cost_record.update_attributes(:member_id => params.permit(:member_id), :location_stock => true)

    redirect_to @costumes_and_cost_record
end
```

I used simple form in view **rent.html.erb**:

```
<%= simple_form_for @costumes_and_cost_record do |f| %>
    <%= f.association :member, :label => "Member", label_method: :to_s, value_method: :member_id, include_blank: true %>

    <%= f.submit "Rent", :controller => :costumes_and_cost_records, :action => :rent_method, :method => :put, :member_id => :member %> <%# updates only member_id, doesnt update :location_stock %>
    <%# link_to "Rent", :controller => :costumes_and_cost_records, :action => :rent_method, :method => :put, :member_id => :member_id %> <%# updates :location_stock, sets member_id = NULL %>
<% end %>
```

Now if I use submit button :member_id updates but controller doesn't update :location_stock.

If I use `link_to :location_stock` updates, but  `:member_id` is set to NULL.

I want to update both attributes. Should I use submit button or link_to and how to fix this issue?

I set **routes.rb** to make both link_to and submit methods in view work:

```
resources :costumes_and_cost_records do
    post 'show'
    get 'rent'
    get 'rent_method'
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need to call rent_method to update member_id

1. Routes changes
   `put 'rent_method'`
2. View changes

   ```
   <%= simple_form_for @costumes_and_cost_record, method: :put, url: [@costumes_and_cost_record, :rent_method] do |f| %>
     <%= f.association :member, :label => "Member", label_method: :to_s, value_method: :member_id, include_blank: true %>

     <%= f.submit "Rent" %> 
   <% end %>
   ```
3. Controller

   ```
   def rent_method
     @costumes_and_cost_record = CostumesAndCostRecord.find(params[:costumes_and_cost_record_id])
     @costumes_and_cost_record.update_attributes(:member_id => member_params[:member_id], :location_stock => true)

     redirect_to @costumes_and_cost_record
   end
   def member_params
     params.require(:costumes_and_cost_record).permit(:member_id)
   end
   ```

Comment: My fault, sorry, replace `url: [:rent_method, @costumes_and_cost_record]` with 
`url: [@costumes_and_cost_record, :rent_method]`

or `put 'rent_method'` with `put 'rent_method', on: :member`

Comment: In second case id will change, I will edit now my original post

Comment: Please check incoming params, I think this is needed in the controller

:member_id => params.require(:costumes_and_cost_record).permit(:member_id)

Comment: Parameters seem to be alright: "costumes_and_cost_record"=>{"member_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Rent", "costumes_and_cost_record_id"=>"27"

Comment: great, then only changes to controller is needed

Answer (score 0):

**Routes**

Firstly, if you want to have `member_id` present, you'll probably be best using [`nested routes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) as follows:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :member do.
   resources :costumes_and_cost_records do
        ...  #-> domain.com/members/2/costumes_and_cost_records/
   end
end
```

This will give you the value required for `params[:member_id]` from your link:

```
<%= link_to "Member", member_costumes_and_cost_records_path(member_id) %>
```

---

**Form**

In your form, you then need to be able to define the `url` correctly (Rails naturally submits to the CRUD based actions, not custom ones):

```
<%= simple_form_for @costumes_and_cost_record, url: your_rent_method_path, method: :patch do |f| %>
```

This will submit to the `rend_method` path, or whichever custom action you wish to request.

--

I would personally keep any activity you have in the controller to a single action - this will allow you to keep all the business logic in one action, which is preferred for the [MVC programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: I have nested routes set correctly and costumes_and_cost_record_rent_method_path submits me to rent_method. The problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It took me 3 days but I finally fixed the problem. Ruslan Kyrychuk's answer was good, but the problem was that I didn't follow Rails naming conventions. I had foreign key: `costumes_and_cost_records.member_id` and primary key:`member.member_id` so I renamed `member.member_id` to `member.id` and that fixed the problem.